# Measuring the conformality or equal-areaness of a projection from the sphere to some surface embedded in $R^3$

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, jacobian, cartography

Suppose I want to map from the sphere to some other surface that is embedded into $\Bbb R^3$, which we will treat as an embedding into $\Bbb R^3$. In this situation, suppose I already have some formula to map from latitudes and longitudes, denoted $(\lambda, \phi)$ to $(x, y, z)$ coordinates in $\Bbb R^3$. I would like to see if this map is equal area, conformal, etc, and in general just evaluate what the metric looks like at some arbitrary point.

I haven't studied this stuff formally, but I would guess that the method would be something like this. Given that I have some function $f: (\lambda, \phi) \mapsto (x, y, z)$, I can get the Jacobian matrix of partial derivatives. This will give two vectors which span a plane tangent to the surface at that point. Then I would guess that, for instance, we can:

- See if these vectors are orthogonal and have the same norm. If this is true everywhere, then the map is conformal.
- Compute the area of the parallelogram formed by the two vectors, and see if it has the same area everywhere. If so, the map is equal area.

However I don't think this is exactly correct, because if we differentiate with respect to the coordinate basis of latitudes and longitudes on the sphere, what we're really doing is mapping from the [equirectangular projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) to $\Bbb R^3$, and the equirectangular projection is neither a conformal nor equal-area map from the sphere to begin with. So some kind of adjustment term will surely be necessary, but I am hoping I have the correct basic idea with the Jacobian. How does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl; dr: In fact, your instincts are precisely correct.

---

In differential geometry, we associate to a parametrization $(x, y, z) = f(\lambda, \phi)$ the three "components of the first fundamental form,"
\begin{align*}
  E &= f_{\lambda} \cdot f_{\lambda} = \|f_{\lambda}\|^{2}, \\
  F &= f_{\lambda} \cdot f_{\phi}, \\
  G &= f_{\phi} \cdot f_{\phi} = \|f_{\phi}\|^{2}.
\end{align*}

- We say $f$ is *conformal* if $E = G$ (coordinate tangent vectors have the same length) and $F = 0$ (orthogonality). (Geometers also speak of *orthogonal* coordinates when $F = 0$.)
- We say $f$ is *area preserving* if $EG - F^{2} = 1$ (the parallelogram spanned by the coordinate tangents has squared area $1$). (In geography, it sounds that the condition is instead that $EG - F^{2}$ is constant.)

For the equirectangular projection (a.k.a., spherical coordinates rolled out flat), we have (up to translation and relabeling of coordinates)
$$
f(\lambda, \phi) = (R\cos\lambda\cos\phi, R\sin\lambda\cos\phi, R\sin\phi).
$$
A short calculation gives
\begin{align*}
  f_{\lambda} &= (-R\sin\lambda\cos\phi, R\cos\lambda\cos\phi, 0), \\
  f_{\phi} &= (-R\cos\lambda\sin\phi, -R\sin\lambda\sin\phi, R\cos\phi);
\end{align*}
thus
$$
E = R^{2}\cos^{2}\phi,\qquad
F = 0,\qquad
G = R^{2}.
$$
This confirms the parametrization is orthogonal, but neither conformal nor area-preserving.